# Is it possible to connect to different databases and treat them all as one?

Tags: database, distributed

Let's say you have access to these databases:
 - MySQL
 - Firebase
 - CouchDB
 - Microsoft SQL Azure Database
 - Google AppEngine Data Store
 - CouchOne

Is there a library or adapter that will combine and treat these as one large database?

I don't care what language the library or adapter would be for.

Thanks,

Comment: Crossing database boundaries (e.g. "distributed access") is inherently hard - while it may be possible to transparently access multiple data-sources, there is no proper handling of "as one". They are simple external data-sources that a clever client may try to aggregate; usually such aggregation is done manually against specific data-sources.

Comment: IMHO the market for such a mega-adapter is incredibly small, developing it would be too expensive to take the risk

Comment: It's already very unlikely that you would have Microsoft SQL Azure DB and Google AppEngine Data Source connected to the same service, since those are only provided by specific providers each, but if you want to combine multiple different datasources and access them at once, Google Dremel, or Apache Drill would be what you are looking fore

Answer (score 0):

No.  But you could write one yourself, publish it and gain lots of respect.